# find all permutations of non-overlapping polygons in R (sp or sf objects)

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

I have a spatial object (say a `Multipolygon` in `sf` or a `SpatialPolygons` in `sp`) and I want to find all the possible permutations of non-overlapping features. Here are some diagrams that illustrate what I am after. Let's say I have the following polygons.

```
library(sf)

# points
a <- st_as_sf(data.frame(lon = c(1,2,3.5,3,6), lat = c(0,1,0,1.5,-3)), coords = c('lon', 'lat'))

# circles
b <- st_buffer(a, 1)

# colors
cols = c('grey', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue')
cols = adjustcolor(cols, alpha.f = .5)

# plot
plot(b, col = cols)
```

[image]

I am after a routine that would create the following 3 objects whose plots would look like:

a.
[image: a]

b.
[image]

c.
[image]

Ideally, the routine would also allow for a threshold on the intersection of polygons.

I think whatever routine I could write myself would take prohibitively long even for moderate-sized objects (say, 150 polygons, yielding lots of possible combinations). I was hoping that someone have already figured this problem out.

Comment: A reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: @Henrik, I always include blue because blue does not overlap with any other polygon. When I include red, I cannot include green, gray or yellow because red overlaps with them. You are right that blue-gray, blue-green and blue-yellow would be a valid permutation given my question. A routine that returns those permutations would be fine. But I guess I am trying to keep as many polygons as possible, so blue-gray-yellow "dominates" blue-gray in a sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
M <- st_overlaps(b, sparse = FALSE) * 1
(M <- 1 - M)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    0    1    1    1
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    1    0    1    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    0    1    1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
colnames(M) <- c('grey', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue')

library(igraph)
A <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(M)
max_cliques(A)
# [[1]]
# + 2/5 vertices, named, from dae1f9f:
# [1] red  blue
#
# [[2]]
# + 3/5 vertices, named, from dae1f9f:
# [1] grey   blue   yellow
#
# [[3]]
# + 3/5 vertices, named, from dae1f9f:
# [1] grey  blue  green
cliques(A)
# ... 
# Omitted, 13 cliques in total
```

First we use `st_overlaps` to get a kind of adjacency matrix, `M`, where two polygons are adjacent in this graph if they overlap in your data. But actually we are going to need `1 - M`, where two polygons are adjacent in this new graph if they don't overlap. That's useful because what you are looking for then corresponds to (maximal) cliques in this graph:

> `cliques` find all complete subgraphs in the input graph, obeying the
>   size limitations given in the min and max arguments.
>
> `max_cliques` finds all maximal cliques in the input graph. A clique in
>   maximal if it cannot be extended to a larger clique. The largest
>   cliques are always maximal, but a maximal clique is not neccessarily
>   the largest.

In this case cliques are sets of polygons where none of the polygons overlap with any of the rest.

Also, as to apply this to `sp` objects, you only need to compute a corresponding `M`. I believe that `over` helps with that.

**Bonus**

As to add the possibility for thresholds, we just need to recompute `M`.

```
aux <- function(x) if (length(x) == 1) x else 0
M <- matrix(1, nrow(a), nrow(a))
for(i in 1:nrow(a))
  for(j in 1:nrow(a))
    M[i, j] <- aux(st_area(st_intersection(b[i, 1], b[j, 1])))
diag(M) <- 0
```

Then, for instance, if we count two polygons as intersecting only if the intersection area is greater than 0.2, we run

```
M <- 1 * (M > 0.2) # Getting threshold-overlaps
M <- 1 - M # The needed adjacency matrix
```

Comment: Nice! I was walking the same path, but used `st_disjoint` instead: `dis <- st_disjoint(b)`;
`g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(dis))`

Comment: A tiny comment on "_maximal cliques in this graph; i.e., subgraphs where everything is connected with everything_." I think the description in `?max_cliques` may be more helpful to understand why blue-red is the only combination of two which is included: "A clique in [sic, should it be 'is'?] maximal if it _cannot be extended_ to a larger clique." (e.g. blue-green could be extended to blue-green-grey, etc). Cheers

Comment: @djas, I added an option to take into account the extent of overlapping area.

Comment: Great answer! I hope you receive more feedback than my +1.

Comment: @JuliusVainora, I am going over everything here. I'll certainly give feedback. Thanks!